# Error while reading body of request message

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to read content of message in WCF project like

```
 var messageContent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.GetBody<byte[]>());
```

But in result I got an error:

> Expecting element 'base64Binary' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'.. Encountered
>   'Element'  with name 'Human', namespace
>   'http://numans.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15'.

Can you please suggest me what Im doing wrong?

Content that I'm sending are:

```
<Human xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://numans.hr-xml.org/2007-04-15">
  <HumanId>
    <guid>c2ee9a7e-c7a8-48e0-910b-47c2012bfa8e</guid>
  </HumanId>
  ...
</Human>
```

Also I tried to read content like:

```
var messageContent = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.ToString();
```

Result of messageContent:

> ...stream...

Comment: can you split up the two method calls and identify where it is throwing? the `GeyBody` or the `GetString`?

Comment: Problem with `GetBody()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`GetBody<T>` is used to deserialize the message body as type T.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195456%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) So when you call `GetBody<byte[]>()`, the deserializer expects base64-encoded binary data but finds the `<Human>` element.

If you only want to read the message body as `string`, use [`GetReaderAtBodyContents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.getreaderatbodycontents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns an `XmlDictionaryReader`, at which you can use [`ReadOuterXml()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readouterxml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to read the body as typed content, create a `Human` class from its XML representation and use `GetBody<Human>()`.

Comment: Thanks. I used: `using (var reader = context.RequestContext.RequestMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents()){Content = reader.ReadOuterXml();}`